# Is passing the Viewmodel to the Controller a good idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am fairly new to MVC and had a question about a form I am creating.  The page has a form at the top and a grid at the bottom.  As people enter data into the form and click the button, the form data is added to the grid below.

My plan is to use a BeginForm and send the form to an HttpPost controller method for processing and then bounce back to the view.  Currently, I am using this for the form on the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddRefund", "Refund", FormMethod.Post))
```

In the controller, I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRefund(RefundModel refund)  
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       (etc...)
```

My problem is that the "refund" object in controller always arrives from the view empty.  From my research, it seems that the model reference in the controller is just there to provide model structure, and NOT to receive the actual model from the view.  I don't understand why this is, however, as it would seem very valuable to be able to send a populated viewmodel from the view to a controller.

Also, how would you guys handle the code for this problem?  How would you collect all of these form submissions from the user, present them to the user in the grid below the form, and then ultimately submit the page and insert all of the items in the grid into the database?

---

edit: here is my view

```
@model RefundsProject.Models.RefundModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddRefund", "Refund", FormMethod.Post))
{
    (all of the form elements are here)

    <input id="button-add" type="submit" value=" Add Refund to List " />
}
```

Eventually, there will be another button at the very bottom of the view that will submit all of the items the user entered into the grid to the database.

Comment: Could you post more of your view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From my research, it seems that the model reference in the controller is just there to provide model structure, and NOT to receive the actual model from the view.

This is completely the opposite of the way ASP.Net MVC was designed.  ASP.Net comes with default ModelBinders that are used to [Bind data from a Form, Querystring, Ajax (Json and XML) to a strongly typed object for a Controller Method](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/08/29/how-to-use-the-asp-net-mvc-modelbinder.aspx).

> My problem is that the "refund" object in controller always arrives from the view empty.

This is most likely due to a lack of knowledge or a misunderstand of how model binders work.

> Also, how would you guys handle the code for this problem?

I would Ajax Post the `RefundModel` back to the controller to validate the refund.  If it is valid, then dynamically create fields in the form that will eventually [model bind back to an IEnumerable/List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) on a new method that will then verify all the refunds, one at a time (to validate the data again).

Here is an Extremely broken down example (probably needs some work, but the important parts are there):

Classes:

```
public class AddRefundsViewModel
{
  public RefundModel Refund { get; set; }
}

public class RefundModel
{
  public string Reason { get; set; }
  public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Methods:

```
public ActionResult AddRefunds()
{
  var model = new AddRefundsViewModel()
  model.Refund = new RefundModel();

  return this.View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateRefund(AddRefundsViewModel model)
{
  var result = new { isValid = modelState.IsValid };

  return this.Json(result);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateRefunds(IEnumerable<RefundModel> model)
{
  var isRefundsValid = true;

  foreach (var refund in model)
  {
    isRefundsValid = TryValidateModel(refund);
    if (!isRefundsValid )
      break;
  }      

  if (isRefundsValid)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    // either someone hacked the form or
    // logic for refunds changed.
  }
}
```

Views:

```
@model AddRefundsViewModel

// assuming RefundController
@using (Html.BeginForm("Refund", "ValidateRefunds", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @html.EditFor(m => m.Refund.Reason)
  @html.EditFor(m => m.Refund.Amount)
  <input type="button" id="addRefundButton" name="addRefundButton" value="add"/>
  <input type="submit" id="submitRefundButton" name="submitRefundButton" value="submit all"/>
}

<!-- jquery -->

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#addRefundButton').on('click', function()
  {
     $.ajax({
       url: '/Refund/ValidateRefund',
       data: $("addRefundForm").serialize(),
       success: function(result)
       {
         if (result.isValid)
         {
           // create new hidden imput elements, and grid
           $("addRefundForm")[0].reset();
         }
         else
         {
           // Refund isn't valid
         }
       }
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> From my research, it seems that the model reference in the controller is just there to provide model structure, and NOT to receive the actual model from the view. I don't understand why this is, however, as it would seem very valuable to be able to send a populated viewmodel from the view to a controller.

Your a bit wrong. There is a difference between ViewModel and Domain Model. View Model is a class that you use to process the logic between views and your domain (business).

Then there is Domain Model (in .net) this is usually some data container objects (POCO). This is anemic. Based on DDD there is a little difference.

So what is the best practive?

It is always good to use a ViewModel object to transfer data between your views and controller.

Then in controller you can use a mapper (automapper or valueinjecter) to transform them.

Now you have your domain object that you can process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had a question however: why isn't public ActionResult AddRefund(RefundModel refund)  enough for me to receive the viewmodel from the controller?  Also, if this is not the correct way to receive the viewmodel from the controller, then how is it received?  Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have `@model YourNameSpace.RefundModel` at the top line of your View?

Comment: Yes, that is at the top of the view.

Comment: I just added the view to the post above.

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm()){` can u use this only ?

Comment: Yes, I bet I could.  I've got [HttpPost] on the controller, so the view should know which method to post to.  Also, there aren't other methods in the controller that it could confuse it with.  May I ask why though?

Answer (score 0):

Using ViewModels to pass data both up and down between controllers and views is completely acceptable.

To help with your model coming up empty issue, inputs, such as `<input id="FirstName" type="text" />` need to have name attributes for the MVC model binder to map what you posted into your `RefundModel` object. In your View code you shared, you only showed a submit button, so it is unclear if your other elements you expect to get mapped have names or not.

To fix my above example of an input tag, you would do `<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" />` or use a Razor helper: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)`